# How to set android:screenOrientation="portrait" for Camera

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

I am using Samsung Galaxy Note to run a phonegap application.
When I take picture, I can see that screen rotates just before entering camera.
How can I disable this?

I have tried to force portrait orientation on both, the main thread & camera activity,
but those do not seem to work:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".App" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.android.camera.Camera"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You are probably better off taking the picture in landscape mode anyway. If you take it in portrait mode there are issues with displaying the image correctly as web browsers don't respect the EXIF orientation parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the permission on the manifest:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />`

[Doc android of balise uses-feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

For example, if your app requires portrait orientation, you should declare `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"/>` so that only devices that support portrait orientation (whether always or by user choice) can install your app. If your application supports both orientations, then you don't need to declare either.

Answer (score 1):

How do you take picture? If you are sending intent to fire up camera application you lose control about orientation changes.   Also note, that before going to sleep and locking screen launcher forces your application into  portrait with an butt-kick regardles of the settings or overriding methods.   Most probably you can not and behaviour on other devices could be different.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` where you are setting screen as portrait.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things here that should be taken into account. First, this

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

has no effect if in the java code there is something like this:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Then, there is this other method that could be bothering you:

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

This would rotate your camera preview.

Hope this helps!