# Forcing landscape on camera android

Tags: java, android-activity, android-manifest, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

#### The problem

I am having problems with forcing the camera to the landscape orientation. I use the plugin "cordova-plugin-camera".

#### The configuration I have so far in the config.xml:

```xml
<gap:config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
<activity
    android:name="com.android.camera.Camera"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"     
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
</gap:config-file>
```

I also added the line below to the widget.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

#### What I know about the configuration

The configuration will be merged with the android manifest by phonegap/cordova. I made the configuration by looking at the configurations I found at the sources below:

- A plugin for cordova/phonegap that is forcing landscape at what I think is the camera:

  http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/barcodescanner

  Go to the heading "Forcing an orientation on Android" and you will see the   same code as below.

```xml
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
    <activity
    android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
    android:exported="false">
```

- A Stackoverflow question where the user who asked the question wanted the camera to stay portrait:
  [How to set android:screenOrientation="portrait" for Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242749/how-to-set-androidscreenorientation-portrait-for-camera)

#### A possible solution?

So I have searched more and found some Java code that forces the camera to stay at the same orientation as the display:

```java
 public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
     int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
 android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
         new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
 android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
 int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
         .getRotation();
 int degrees = 0;
 switch (rotation) {
     case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
     case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
     case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
     case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
 }

 int result;
 if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
     result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
     result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
 } else {  // back-facing
     result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
 }
 camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

**source:**    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)

I am really struggling on how to append this code to my app. Do I need to make a plugin? Or is there another way to append this code to my app?

#### What I want

I hope somebody can tell me what's wrong with my configuration or tell me how to append the java code to my project. I am open for other solutions on how to force the camera to stay in landscape. **Any help is appreciated.**

#### More info

More information about the gap:config-file element:
http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html

I have also created a question on:

- [community.phonegap.com](http://gsfn.us/t/4sxfp)
- [the repository from the barcodescanner](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/BarcodeScanner/issues/17)